# How to use sysctl on UNIX variants, e.g. macOS, to read information normally found in /proc/self on Linux?

Tags: linux, kernel, macos, proc, sysctl

I've been using `/proc/self` for a long time to read process-related information like `/proc/self/maps` etc.

However, on some UNIX variants, like macOS, the `procfs` filesystem is not implemented; but as this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200103161748/http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/ancient/procfs/) states, it should be possible to obtain similar information using `sysctl`.

Reading output from `sysctl -a`, I find that information is not directly associated to any specific process, but instead relates to the system or kernel.

So, how can I use `sysctl` to read the information, normally present in `/proc/self` on Linux distributions, on UNIX variants like macOS?

I want to e.g. get `/proc/self/maps` on macOS.

Comment: On FreeBSD you can also display that info with `procstat vm PID`. Also the `sysctl(3)` api allows access to some process info (don't know if that includes its vm), but it's not used by the `sysctl(1)` utility. As to MacOS, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058005/mac-os-x-equivalent-of-virtualquery-or-proc-pid-maps) on stackoverflow may help you, but I have no idea about it, as I don't have or use a MacOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your observation that sysctl predominantly contains system-wide
parameters is apt.  It also follows somewhat from the name `sysctl` (which suggests SYStem ConTroL), and [the man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysctl&manpath=Darwin%208.0.1%2Fppc)'s description of "`sysctl - get or set kernel state`."

Some BSD systems do offer optional `procfs` filesystem support which can be mounted under `/proc`, such as FreeBSD:

```
# mount -t procfs procfs /proc
```

This provides some of the functionality, but is perhaps most often used for compatibility purposes when running Linux binaries in emulation mode, rather than for definitive inquiries into the run-time statistics of specific native BSD processes.  Unfortunately, OS X doesn't support `procfs` filesystems, to my knowledge.

And more generally, BSD systems don't use `/proc`, so the answer of what to use to replace a particular `/proc`-based query varies depending on what the specific query is.  Given the recent edit to your post, you may find this command helpful to display memory usage for a specific process:

```
$ sudo vmmap $$
```

Comment: I want to e.g. get `/proc/self/maps` on macOS.

Comment: Your question might be the same as [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1057887/how-to-inspect-memory-map-on-osx) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782228/retrieve-ram-info-on-a-mac).

Comment: @Shuzheng also, see edit.